# NPC won't settle down in one of my houses

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have beaten the wall of flesh, so I am in hard mode. There is one NPC that wants to move in, it constantly says it. I have 2 open houses that are unoccupied, and it will not move in. I have made multiple houses trying to get it to move in. I have the Demolitionist, Witch Doctor, Guide, Mechanic, Goblin Tinkerer, Steampunk, Wizard, Arms Dealer, and Dryad, the name of the NPC that won't settle down in one of my houses is Shime Ji. My 2 available houses each have 2 torches, a door, a chair, and walls and a 7 tall by 10 wide frame at least. One of my houses has a star in a bottle for lighting, but my guide lived there before, and for some reason moved to one of my other houses. If you know what is going wrong with it, please respond.

Comment: Is there corruption/crismon biome around ? It can prevent a house to be inhabitable.

Answer (score 4):

Shime ji is one of the variations of the truffle. For him to settle, you need to create him a house in the mushroom biome and bring it to the surface ideally. So go underground, get mushroom biome seeds, and plant them. They can only be planted on mud, so you will have to create a mud platform. A biome starts when ~50 blocks of the biome blocks are present. Music starts playing if you succesfully made the mushroom biome. Then make him a house in the mushroom newly created mushroom biome. If he still doesn't settle, make the biome bigger.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably a truffle,
They need at least 50+ blocks of mushroom grass blocks (grown by mushroom seeds, on mud blocks, so start making a mud platform!) and a house in that biome.